# How do I specify a default subcommand in yargs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, yargs

I'm using `yargs` to create a build tool with subcommands for "build", "link", "clean", etc.

I'd like to be able to type `./build.js` with no arguments and invoke the "build" subcommand handler as a default.

I was able to do it thusly:

```
var argv = yargs
  .usage("I am usage.")
  .command('bundle', 'Create JS bundles', bundle)
  .command('link', 'Symlink JS files that do not need bundling', link)
  .command('clean', 'Remove build artifacts', clean)
  .command('build', 'Perform entire build process.', build)
  .help('help')
  .argv;
if (argv._.length === 0) { build(); }
```

But it seems a bit hacky to me, and it will likely cause problems if I ever want to add any additional positional arguments to the "build" subcommand.

Is there any way to accomplish this within the semantics of yargs? The documentation on `.command()` could be more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yargs doesn't seem to provide this functionality by itself. There is a third party package on NPM that augments yargs to do what you want. https://www.npmjs.com/package/yargs-default-command

```
var yargs = require('yargs');
var args = require('yargs-default-command')(yargs);

args
  .command('*', 'default command', build)
  .command('build', 'build command', build)
  .args;
```

Comment: Why is it that the answer to everything in the node ecosystem inevitably "install another package"?

Comment: Because monolithic libraries that try to solve every problem ever encountered are cumbersome and unmaintainable

Comment: This is supported natively since v7: https://github.com/yargs/yargs/blob/master/docs/advanced.md

Answer (score 6):

As commented by @sthzg, you can have [default commands](https://github.com/yargs/yargs/blob/master/docs/advanced.md#default-commands) now:

```
const argv = require('yargs')
  .command('$0', 'the default command', () => {}, (argv) => {
    console.log('this command will be run by default')
  })
```